# Sending Windows CRLF over ssh from Linux machine

Tags: sql-server, windows, bash, ssh, cygwin

I need to run a certain batch file on a Windows Server 2012 remotely using a Linux machine.

Now the issue is that, the batch file does some SQL Server related stuff (dropping the database and then restoring it again using SQL scripts). Problem is, after it has done it's job, it needs a push in the form of an enter pressed in the Windows terminal to come out of the 'hanging state' or whatever that state is. I have verified this by running the batch file directly using PowerShell on the target.

So how do I emulate this behavior from Linux? FYI, I've installed CYGWIN's openssh on the Windows system and I have set up passwordless SSH access so that part has been taken care of. Nonetheless, what is confusing me here is how do I encode those control characters into a string that is passed over SSH

I've tried passing `\r\n` which is not recognized by the CYGWIN deamon that is running on the windows machine. Of course it won't since it emulates the UNIX env on windows. However `\n` or rather `\\n` (if that is the correct way to escape)

This question (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53581/sending-function-keys-f1-f12-over-ssh) talks about sending control characters over SSH. However when I append `^M` to my SSH command string, I get the same error:
`bash: ^M command not found`

Or if you think there could be a better way to make sure that batch file finishes without giving it this 'push' please let me know.

As an aside, how do I check if the command invoked over SSH is indeed running on the remote machine? P.S. I don't want to check it via SSH, but on the windows machine itself. I mean how would it look like in the process listing?? Like on Linux I can list all SSH connections using `who -a` or `ps aux | grep -i sshd` so is there something I can execute on the Windows Server 2012 machine to make sure my script is done or still running?

Comment: Can you save the commands to run in a script, copy it from the Linux machine into the Windows machine and use ssh to run that script remotely?

Comment: `^M` is not a string. if you are using vi in ssh, in `insert` mode you press `Ctrl + v` then press `Ctrl + m` will get `^M`.

Comment: I wanted to see how an 'enter' gets encoded, so I press `Ctrl+v` and then I press the `enter` key and I see a `^M` on the terminal. I do this because I connect to CYGWIN on the Windows machine and hence a unix-like environment is supposed to interpret `^M` as an enter

Comment: for the command that needs to "return" try run it like : 
`yourcommand < /dev/null &> /dev/null & disown`